# MS Word crashes if I set the space separator in the list

Tags: microsoft-word, crash, microsoft-word-2010, list

I have a style "Picture #" for signing pictures in a document, which is based on a standard Word's style of a multi-level list

[image]

If I set up the space separator between the numerator and text Word suddenly crashes after some period of time (it's closing without saving with a critical problem). Here is an example of how it looks:

[image]

Does anybody know the reason for the crash?
Do you have any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

**If its just that one word document** is could be corrupt you can try repair it by opening word and going to browse

[image]

Then you click the dropdown on the open box and select open and repair

[image]

Now select and open your document and see if you can set the space operator
.

**If its all word documents**
Go to Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features
under here you will find Microsoft Office XXXX right click it and click change

[image]

It will give you a few options when you click change
**Don't Select smart repair only do the quick one** if it gives you the option between the two